# What is the relationship between the Windows API and the C run time library?

Tags: c, winapi

What is the relationship between the Windows API and the C run time library?

Comment: What C runtime library are you referring to? (atleast there's no such thing that I know of). You mean VC++ runtime library?

Comment: @pop: There is a C runtime library. It includes all the functions required by the C standard that a platform supports.

Comment: @Jason Coco: You do not know anymore than anyone else whether the OP meant C or C++. He said C and tagged it C++. There is a very good chance he doesn't know C != C++.

Comment: @Rich B: granted, but the answer is essentially the same anyway. ALso, he wrote C twice in his subject and question. C++ pops up first on the list of tags, and if you're new to SO it's very easy to accidently choose the first suggestion instead of the one you typed. I still have it happen to me.

Comment: @Jason Coco: I think there's a difference between C standard library and a "runtime library", the C standard library it's not a runtime library, it's fully statically linked into the application by the linker, without any dynamic linking or binding.

Comment: Quote wikipedia: "Though often confused with the C Standard Library because of this packaging, the C Runtime Library is not a standardized part of the language and is vendor-specific." The C runtime library doesn't exist as a standard, therefore it can be ignored,it's at best a implementation detail

Comment: C++ makes more sense. It is not very important as a difference, but changing it back so late in the game has made this thread awful. Oh well. I tried.

Comment: @Pop Catalin: Totally agreed, but Microsoft literature calls the C standard library "C runtime library" regardless. There are also number of platforms that don't statically link to the C std library (e.g., modern Linux, OS X, etc.). I dunno about Windows though.

Comment: @Pop Catalin: I know what Wikipedia says, but it's not the end-all, be-all authority on English word use ;) I do agree with that definition, but again, MS calls it the "C runtime library" and he clearly is working with MS, so...

Comment: @Rich B: It may make more sense, but I believe the OP meant C and accidently tagged C++. It's extremely easy to do with the SO system when trying to tag C. Hopefully he will come and correct it himself?

Comment: @Jason: I highly doubt it. He is more likely a drive by questioner. He is looking for cheap rep as indicated by the other closed questions he is currently asking. My point is/was that this thread is a mess now.

Comment: @Rich B: okay, I concede that you're probably right. Shall we re-tag to C++ and just delete our respective comments?

Comment: @Jason: Nope, I think we should leave it alone. The damage is done. Let's not further muddle this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a nutshell: The Windows API contains all the functions defined specifically for Windows. The C run-time library contains all the functions that are required by standard C.

The physical libraries that implement these functions may be a single file (library), split across two separate libraries or split into many libraries, depending on the operating system and the actual API/service you are using.

For example, when creating files, the C standard includes the function:

`fopen`

to open and create files, etc., while the Win32 API (for example) defines functions like:

`CreateFile`

to create and manipulate files. The first one will be available wherever a standard C run-time library is available while the second one will only be available on a Windows machine that supports the Win32 API.

Answer (score 8):

If you mean the standard C library (msvcrt.dll I assume). Then not much at all. The majority of the windows API is implemented in separate dlls (very much of it is in user32.dll or kernel32.dll). In fact, some of these functions in the Windows API are just thin wrappers around system calls where the actual work is done in the kernel itself.

Also, as [ocdecio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424123/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-windows-api-and-the-c-run-time-library#424138) said, it is entirely reasonable to assume that certain parts of the C standard library are implemented using windows APIs. And for certain cases like string manipulations, vice versa.

EDIT: since which dlls are implemented in terms of others has come into question, i've checked with dependancy walker and here is my findings:

```
kernel32.dll depends on:
  ntdll.dll

user32.dll depends on:
  gdi32.dll
  kernel32
  ntdll.dll
  advapi.dll
  msimg32.dll
  powerprof.dll (this dll references msvcrt.dll for some string functions)
  winsta.dll

msvcrt.dll depends on:
  kernel32.dll (yes it does have imports for CreateFileA)
  ntdll.dll
```

based off of this, I believe that msvcrt is build on top of the win32 API.

Comment: another downvote? could the downvoters at least explain. I don't believe my answer to be wrong.

Comment: I think the answer is good, so +1... I can't stand it when people downvote a reasonable answer without leaving a comment.

Comment: Is there any difference between C standard library and C runtime libraray?

Comment: Rich, why "did" that for you? i think it's right. fopen could very well be implemented using OpenFile/CreateFile

Comment: Dazza, that really deserves its own separate question, not a follow-up in a comment.

Comment: dazza, people mean the part of the c standard library that your program uses at runtime - as opposed stuff that it uses at compile time (i.e macro definitions). other ppl mean a specific c standard library implementation when they talk about "c runtime library"

Comment: other people say "runtime library" means a library that is bound to your program at loading time, as opposed at linking time. yet another group says runtime libs are those that do not entirely consist only of header files.

Comment: I would probably define the "runtime" as the contents of what is usually called crt0 (which stands for c runtime). Which really only *needs* to do some basic pre/post main work (allocate stdio streams and such, call exit with the return value of main, etc).

Comment: @Rich B: what do you think fopen does if it doesn't eventually call CreateFile? I suppose it could directly call the system call "NtOpenFile" like CreateFile eventually does, but that would just be duplicated code. It makes more sense for it to be built ontop of the existing API.

Comment: Also, (I dunno if MS cared enough to avoid it, but) if it does call the system call directly, that would make the dll itself not not always transferable between different versions of the OS. Occasionally MS has be known to change them (see http://www.metasploit.com/users/opcode/syscalls.html)

Comment: Implementation really doesn't matter... fopen is part of the C Standard Library (which MS calls C Runtime Library, but whatever), CreateFile is part of the Win32 API. They could all be rolled up in one giant static archive, and it still wouldn't matter. The diff is they're 2 sets of APIs

Comment: No need to assume anything. The CRT source is included with Visual C++, and yes, it uses Win32 API calls.

Answer (score 4):

Win32 is a completely different beast to the CRT.

CRT is something that needs to be linked into your project when you use C or C++ functions/features (such as printf or cout).

Win32 is a set of libraries that need to be linked into your project when you use Windows features (like GetWindowText).

Answer (score 1):

What they are:

- The Windows API is the API exported by the Microsoft Windows[TM] Operating System
- The C run time library is the "standard library" which is shipped with the C compiler by the compiler vendor, and which is available on whichever/any operating system (for example, Unix) is targetted by the compiler

What their relationship is:

- They are distinct, but both equally available to C++ applications running on Windows
- On Windows, the C standard library is implemented by invoking the underlying Windows API (to allocate memory, open files, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

C run time library is based on the Windows API

Answer (score -2):

Unix System calls are analogy with Windows API.

Comment: What? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Rich, i think it does make limited sense: unix syscalls <=> windows API, msvcrt <=> glibc